# MongoDB Drive C# Index not used

Tags: c#, mongodb, indexing

In MongoDB:

```
db.estr.createIndex({_id:1, Atualizar:-1});
```

In C#

```
var a = await db.dados.Distinct(x=>x.codigo).toListAsync();
var b = await db.estr.find(x=>!a.contains(x._id) && x.Atualizar).toListAsync();
```

Index Stats

```
{
    "name" : "_id_1_Atualizar_-1",
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1.0,
        "Atualizar" : -1.0
    },
    "host" : "OMNIIS2012HOM:27017",
    "accesses" : {
        "ops" : NumberLong(0), <----- not utilizade
        "since" : ISODate("2020-03-24T11:00:25.011-03:00")
    }
}
```

Doing a search on MongoDB the index is not being called
x.Atualizar are Boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query is doing an inequality match against the first field in the index spec, so it must scan the entire index, and for each `_id` value that satisfies the query, check for a matching `Atualizar` value.  In many situations this will perform worse than a collection scan, so the index might never be used.

If you were to swap the order of the fields in your index, i.e.

```
db.estr.createIndex({Atualizar:-1, _id:1})
```

the query executor would be able to begin scanning at the first key matching `Atualizar`, and select all of the matching documents with 2 scans of the `_id` values.  This should perform much better, so the query planner should select this index.

Note that for very small data sets where all of the documents fit into RAM, collection scan is usually fastest.